# Video not filling width of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have my browser (chrome) in full screen mode on Desktop. I am trying to make my video fit to the screen width and height with css. I however can see a 1px vertical line on the far right hand side of the screen that isn't covered by the video. Here is my `HTML`. I've also tried directly setting my video width and height to `screen.width;` and `screen.height;` but I get the exact same results.

```
<body>
    <div class="fill-screen">
        <video id="57" autoplay="" loop="" class="asset current"><source src="myvideo.mp4"></video>
    </div>
</body>
```

and my CSS:

```
* { cursor: none !important; }
body{
    margin:0px !important;

}

.hidden{
    display:none;
}

div.fill-screen {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

video{


  /* prevent browser from warping video */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;


}
```

Comment: It seems you don't want to warp/stretch the video - are you sure the video dimensions are identical to your viewport?

Comment: Use  `:root{box-sizing: border-box}` and `video {width: 100vw; height: 100vh;}`

Comment: Why is this question tagged as "Java"?

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 17px;
        }

        #myVideo {
            position: fixed;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
        }

        .content {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            color: #f1f1f1;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>


</body>

</html>
```

more info: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fullscreen_video.asp

Comment: Adding some explanation of what you changed and why would really improve this answer.